# Saving Newsletter data fails intermittently

Tags: civimail, mosaico

We use CiviCRM for Newsletters, this is hosted by IMBA (International Mountain Bike Association), I do not know what version or CMS they use, their customer service has not been responsive to this issue so I am posting here to see if I can get some information to provide to them. We have a problem where it does not consistently save edits.  Does not give an error, it just doesn't save work when pressing the save button.  It is intermittent and will not save 1 time, and then 1 minute later will save.  I have tested it with changes of 1 character, it is not failing on quotes or double quotes - anyone have this experience also?[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Could you please provide more information to help people to answer your question. What is 'IMBA'? I've not heard of this. Which version of CiviCRM are you using? And which CMS (Drupal, WordPress or Joomla)?

Comment: @WilliamMortada I added some more information per your comment - thank you

Comment: also explain, if you can, if they are using Mosaico for the newsletters or just traditional civimail. (ps provided support for many years to IMBA years ago but no idea how they are set up these days)

Comment: @petednz-fuzion  I have reached out to a contact there, I think Mosiaco as I've heard that term, but will confirm.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion   Mosiaco

Comment: according to this there is now autosave with mosaico - https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/444 - what version of the extension are you using (you may not have access to the Extensions or System Status page to find out unfortunately)

Comment: hmm. also you say 'when pressing the save button'. can you add a screenshot just so we are all clear what is being used - when I view a mosaico mailing screen such as I get when i install mosaico on dmaster and create one eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/a/#/mailing/1 i do not have a 'save' button, only a 'close' and a 'test' both of which would trigger a Save.

Comment: add extension via https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1&action=browse&selectedChild=addnew

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I added a screenshot

Comment: The first screenshot seems mosaico-ish but doesn't look like the one in civi - it looks like it's either custom or being used separately on the CMS side. The second shot does look a bit like the one in civi but as noted above there would be close and test buttons. My guess overall is that this isn't part of civi and is a separate use of mosaico.